# PHP Operators Do not work?

Tags: php

I have some code here that is acting really weird on my website.

```
if($balance != $expectedBalance){
echo "balance: ".$balance." - Type:".gettype($balance);
echo "<br>";
echo "expected: ".$expectedBalance." - Type:".gettype($expectedBalance);
```

But the output of this code is:

> balance: 69.95 - Type:double
>
> expected: 69.95 - Type:double

How is that, its really making me go crazy when developing my website.
And how do I make it so the if statement actually only runs if the are diffrent?

Comment: Try `var_dump($balance)` and `var_dump($expectedBalance)` to see exactly what is in those values and the size.

Comment: Floating point numbers are not exact. You can have two floating point numbers that print the same but have some differences in low-order bits.

Comment: Could be floating point inaccuracies, but since there are only 2 decimal places I doubt it. Perhaps instead of just echo'ing the value you could do a var_dump on both $balance and $expectedBalance.

Comment: It's best not to use floating point for money for this reason.

Comment: @aynber when using var_dump i get "float(69.95) " on both variables...?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn when using var_dump i get "float(69.95) " on both variables...?